# NGINX configurations: Setup SSL Certificate for multiple ports using one domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, nginx-config

I've two website which I built in Django. My one website which running on port 8000 is secured with a SSL certificate and I have running second website which is running on port 8001 without SSL . My default file (etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mbucks_ssl) looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mbucks.in *.mbucks.in;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mbucks.in *.mbucks.in;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mbucks.in/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mbucks.in/privkey.pem;

    # Additional SSL configurations...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 240s;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mbucks.in:8001;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mbucks.in/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mbucks.in/privkey.pem;

    # Additional SSL configurations...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 240s;
    }
}
```

I have tried to run both website on wildcard ssl but could get success Could you please healp me where I'm making mistake
https://mbucks.in and https://*.mbucks.in run and show website which is on port 8000
but https://mbucks.in:8001 not reachable which is on port 8001